# How to access a container/service port in swarm without publishing the port to the outside world?

Tags: docker-compose, networking, docker-swarm

It is possible to docker-compose to forward a port to the container from `localhost` only, by writing the desired `ports` configure in `docker-compose.yml`, e.g. `127.0.0.1:8080:80`.

In docker swarm this does not work and the published port is visible from the internet.

How then can I access the container port only from localhost without opening the port to the internet?

I tried configuring iptables to deny connection to port `iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 5432 -j DROP`, but because of the settings from docker for iptables, that didn't work.

Comment: Seems like this wouldn't be likely to be a feature in docker swarm since each host would have a different IP.  Are you combining docker and non-docker resources?  If it is just docker, you don't have to publish the port to use it.  Just set up an internal network.

Comment: @PeterTurner I want to access postgres, which is running in swarm, from my computer in ValentinaStudio) Previously with docker-compose this was possible. After I switched to swarm I'm looking for an alternative to this method

Comment: OK - it makes sense that it's possible with docker-compose, it seems like it wouldn't make sense to be possible with docker-swarm, since the purpose for the program is a distributed application.  Your iptables command would work, if you used `-I` instead of `-A`

Answer (score 2):

The container can be accessed via the ip which belongs to the `docker_gwbridge` interface.

I was able to find out the ip address of the container on the `docker_gwbridge` interface by running the `ifconfig` command in the container itself:

```bash
$ docker exec <container-id> ifconfig
```

This way the container can be accessed from `host machine` for example by `172.18.0.2:5432`, without having to publish port `5432`.

---

Trying to find out the ip address via `docker inspect <container-id> (or <service-name> or <network-id>)` in swarm services did not lead to the desired result, because the ip from the `docker_gwbridge` interface was not displayed there. And the "internal" ip (something like 10.0.4.6) was not available from `host machine`.